# Double line break HTML tag

Tags: html, css, newline, line-breaks

I am creating a website and I find myself doing `</br></br>` a lot in order to create a new paragraph looking like this...

```
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2
```

I have already created a `<tab>` tag to indent paragraphs but I am wondering if I could create a `<break>` tag and in puts in two new lines to save me some time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

-Henry

Comment: Why don't you break this paragraph in two paragraphs ?

Comment: What do you mean? @dystroy

Comment: The right direction is called [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

Comment: On a side note, `</br>` isn't correct schematics. That's a closing tag, and the linebreak tag is never opened. You should be using either `<br />` (a self closed tag) or `<br>` (legacy code).

Comment: you really shouldn't "make" new tags. There is a <p> tag for just this thing.

Comment: @dystroy I know what CSS is... How do you think I created my `<tab>` tag? Using `tag { padding-left:2.5em; }`

Comment: Use `<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p>`

Comment: @Mike Thanks Mike. I never understood the different between </br> <br> and <br />

Comment: @rlemon Should I not of created my `<tab>` tag to indent paragraphs? Is that bad?

Comment: @HenryHarris You should probably create a class like .tab or .indent that has the same rule, and put that class on the paragraphs which you want indented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `<p>` are not needed semanticly(?), you may change `<br/>` defaut values:

```
br {
  margin:2.5em 0;/* FF for instance */
  line-height:5em;/* chrome for instance */
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cJwDhI  <=here it's 5em, to make it obvious :)

Comment: Thanks for actually answering what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `<pre>` tag. It saves the formatting within.

```
<pre>
My first line.

My second line after two line breaks.
</pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use the `p` tag: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html

```
<p>Paragraph 1</p>

<p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

as a side note: you really should look into using [semantic html](http://alistapart.com/article/semanticsinhtml5)

Comment: Should I not of created my `<tab>` tag to indent paragraphs? Is that bad practice?

Comment: yes that is very bad practice for the most part. you can use existing tags (like `i`) and override their default values.

Comment: But if `i` italicizes text what if I want to use that? But I changed `i` to indent.

Comment: A better way to indent your paragraphs would be to give them a class (e.g. <p class="tab">) and style it with a margin-left property (e.g. .tab {margin-left: 4em;})